# The current request is not multipart

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I have generated a Spring REST web service from Swagger API. The code for the POST Service is given below

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "class io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2016-10-24T09:36:32.738Z")

@Api(value = "addUser", description = "the addUser API")
public interface AddUserApi {

@ApiOperation(value = "Add an additional user", notes = "This service is used to add and additional user to the list of users.", response = Void.class, tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = Void.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Unexpected error", response = Void.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Void> addUserPost(


@ApiParam(value = "Unique id of the user to be added.", required=true ) @RequestPart(value="userId", required=true)  Integer userId,


@ApiParam(value = "Name of the user to be added.", required=true ) @RequestPart(value="name", required=true)  String name,


@ApiParam(value = "Profession of the user to be added.", required=true ) @RequestPart(value="profession", required=true)  String profession);

}
```

I'm posting the data to this service using the content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". But the issue that I'm facing is that on posting I'm getting an error JSON as response which is given below.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1477401894250,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException",
  "message": "The current request is not a multipart request",
  "path": "/UserManagement/rest/UserService/addUser"
}
```

According to my knowledge multipart is only needed when we are uploading a file from the form, I'm not uploading a file. I have searched and every result is based on file upload. My swagger YAML is given below.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
version: 1.0.0
title: Extended User Management API
description: >-
  This is communicate with an extended user management webservice to test the swagger API for learning
schemes:
   - http
basePath: /UserManagement/rest/UserService
host: '127.0.0.1:8089'
produces:
   - application/json
paths:
  /users:
     get:
       responses:
         '200':
            description: An array of users
            schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/User'
          default:
            description: Unexpected error
            schema:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
   /addUser:
      post:
      summary: Add an additional user
      description: This service is used to add and additional user to the list of users.
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
        - name: user_id
          in: query
          description: Unique id of the user to be added.
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int32
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: Name of the user to be added.
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: profession
          in: query
          description: Profession of the user to be added.
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
           description: OK
        default:
           description: Unexpected error
           schema:
             $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
definitions:
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      user_id:
        type: integer
        format: int32
        description: This is unique id that is assigned to each user.
      name:
        type: string
        description: This is the name of the user
      profession:
        type: string
        description: This is the profession that the user holds
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
      fields:
        type: string
```

Can someone pleas assist me and tell me why I'm facing this issue and how to solve this. Please inform if you require any other details to analyse the problem.

Request headers are as follows

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

**Edited:**

I tried changing the consumes to "application/json" and I got the response as given below

```
{
  "timestamp": 1477464487595,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
  "path": "/UserManagement/rest/UserService/addUser"
}
```

Request header is given below

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: can you paste the request header?

Comment: add your entire request plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mapping contains **consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }** means it accepts content type that are binarym, change that to following to accept json data type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    consumes = { "application/json" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Void> addUserPost(..)
```

Comment: I tried changing this and I got "Unsupported Media Type" 415 error. I have a form and I need to the get the data of that form to the web service. You can see this in yaml post parameters written in swagger

Comment: I edited the contents added the new request header and response

Comment: Thanks man, I solved the issue. I had to change the method parameter also to get the correct implementation and I also changed the parameters for the POST operation to the object "User" (mentioned in definitions) and in to body